# Adding file upload to bootstrap contact form

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Im using bootstrap modern business template, but cant figure out how to add file upload to the contact form which will be sent to a email address. I tried many different things but not good with php.

http://erotikus-munka.co.uk/jelentkezni.html

http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/modern-business/    <-- template i use

Comment: *"I tried many different things but not good with php."* - Show us one of them then.

Comment: ok, im gonna upload it to the website as everytime when i try to copy the code here it wont accept some of the code and it will be shown as normal text

Comment: If it's shown as text, then you may not have an `.php` extension. That is required to be that when running as PHP.

Comment: http://erotikus-munka.co.uk/jelentkezni2.html

Comment: no, i mean if you copy and paste the code here such as    `<div> </<div>`

Comment: You have no form tags in that page.

Comment: when i try to copy the code of my html, php, and js files, it wont work for some reason and after the first few line it will break the codeblock

Comment: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

Comment: I added form tags just now. Still same, js validation wont even do anything let alone to send an email

Comment: Fred if I just add these codes to my existing ones, will it work as on the first link i uploaded? Because I want the uploaded files to be emailed as an attachment

Comment: plus I wont be able to modify those in a secure way...so that is unusable for me